# Looking for a free Adobe Acrobat alternative for Business

Tags: gratis, pdf, pdf-viewer, pdf-editor

Recently I switched from Microsoft Office to Open Office and it saved me a lot of money. I was wondering if there's a similar application for Windows that can replace Adobe Acrobat. Something that can edit forms and insert clients signature via Wacom tablet in PDF files. Also, I will be using it for commercial business so I need it to be distributed under GNU General Public License.

Comment: since you don't specified a OS, this is a nice point to start...: https://pdfreaders.org/

Comment: Here you can a list of softwares - http://www.filehorse.com/search?q=pdf

Comment: I am too busy ot post an answer, but I doubt that you can beat  https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-editor

Answer (score 1):

OpenOffice/LibreOffice can export any document as a PDF file.

OO/LO can also create PDF forms, at least well enough to be able to programmatically fill them out using PHP and FDF..

The "signing" of a PDF file is an Adobe thing as far as I can tell.  Of course, you could use gpg/pgp and sign documents with your public/private key pair...

Answer (score 0):

I give you a free software to create a PDF.

> PDFCreator: Use PDFCreator to create PDFs from any printable program,
>   as well as encrypt and autosave files based on predefined terms.
>
> PDFescape: This online PDF solution is a reader, editor, form filler,
>   and form designer. All you need to use it is a JavaScript enabled web
>   browser.
>
> PDF reDirect: The freeware PDF reDirect offers loads of robust
>   features, including PDF creation, previews, encryption, and more, that
>   go a long way to replacing Adobe.

**Primo PDF**
[WebLink Here](http://www.primopdf.com/)

**PDFTKB**
[WebLink Here](http://angusj.com/pdftkb/)